# How to add a score to a list of high scores?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a highscore list of the top 6 scores.
Is there a way every time a new score is registered, it searches though the list, and if the new score beats any of the old ones, it takes the place above, and deletes the last place?

Example:

```py
top10 = ["name1:100", "name2:97", "name3:96", "name4:94", "name5:91"]
newscore = "95"
newname = "name6"
newLocation = top10.search(theClosestNumberUnder, top10)
top10.insert(newLocation, f"{youname}:{recc}")
```

Comment: Why are you using data in the form `name1:100`?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of solving this, a ugly way, or a proper way.

### Ugly way

```py
top10 = ["name1:100", "name2:97", "name3:96", "name4:94", "name5:91"]
newscore = "95"
newname = "name6"
top10.append(f"{newname}:{newscore}")
top10.sort(key=lambda i: int(i.split(":")[1]), reverse=True)  # Sort the scores
del top10[10:]  # Remove all scores after the first 10
```

### Proper Way

```py
top10 = [(100, "name1"), (97, "name2"), ...]  # Different format so you don't have to convert to strings and back to ints every time
top10.append((12, "name6"))  # Notice the double parentheses, since we are passing a tuple
top10.sort(reverse=True)  # Tuples are sorted lexicographically by default so no key is needed
del top10[10:]  # Again delete extra elements
```

Another advantage of this method is that it won't crash if the name contains a literal `:` character.

Answer (score -1):

another way to do it with a class and the operator override greater than:

```
tab_score=[]
class Score:
    def __init__(self,name,score):
      self.score=score
      self.name=name
    def __gt__(self,other_score):
          if self.score > other_score.score :
              return True
          else:
              return False
def ajout_score(tab,score):
    for i in range(10):
        if len(tab)==i:
            tab.append(score)
            break
        elif score > tab[i]:
            save=tab[i]
            tab[i]=score
            score=save
    
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name1",10))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name2",100))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name3",1))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name4",5))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name5",7))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name6",155))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name7",40))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name8",87))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name9",45))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name10",2))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name11",2))
ajout_score(tab_score,Score("name12",7))

for score in tab_score:
    print(score.name,":",score.score)
```

output:

```
name6 : 155
name2 : 100
name8 : 87
name9 : 45
name7 : 40
name1 : 10
name5 : 7
name12 : 7
name4 : 5
name11 : 2
```